# scan dir with limiting files number?

Tags: php, directory

I have written some code to print files inside folder with a limit and offset (like MySQL's `LIMIT`).

My code:

```
/*
files:
.
..
read.txt
*/
$dir = "lab";
$limit = 2;
$file_id = 1;
$start = 1;
$files = array();
$dh  = opendir($dir);
while (false !== ($filename = readdir($dh))) {
    if($file_id > $start and $file_id >= $limit){
        $files[$file_id] = $filename;
    }
    $file_id++;
}   
print_r($files);
/*
files:
Array ( [2] => .. [3] => read.txt ) 
*/
```

My folders may contain 1000 or more files and this function will be executed for each visitor.

So I want to do this job without looping, is that possible? If it isn't, is there any way to make this faster?

Answer (score 2):

http://www.php.net/scandir is probably the best way to avoid looping yourself.

If you'd rather, you can also implement a basic START/LIMIT system like this

```
$start = 5;
$limit = 20;

$thisFile = 0;

while (false !== ($filename = readdir($dh))) {
    // Check the start
    if ($thisFile < $start)
        continue;
    $thisFile++;

    // Check the end
    if ($thisFile > $limit)
        break;

    // Your other code can go in here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve whole list of files within directory without any loops with [scandir](http://php.net/scandir).

After you've retrieved an array of files you can apply any kind of filtering (using [array_filter](http://php.net/array_filter)) and limiting (using [array_slice](http://php.net/array_slice))